# Layout in HTML web page

Tags: html, css

I am new with HTML web design and all the languages involving it (php, JavaScript, CSS, etc.)
I would like some help to make my HTML layout look as follows:

[image]

I have the following code, but I don't know how to modify it to make it look as I want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.class1{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}
.class2{
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}
.class3 {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="class1" style="background-color:#9BCB3B;">
    <p>left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="class2" style="background-color:#1AB99E;">
    <p>Top right</p>
  </div>
  <div class="class3" style="background-color:#F36F25;">
    <p>Buttom right</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the code snippet for the details of the change. Basically, all 3 `<div>` are using `float: left` with `width: 50%`. In `<body>` scope, add `height: 100vh;` to set the height of body.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .class1 {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .class2,
    .class3 {
      width: 50%;
      float: left;
      height: 50%;
    }
       
    p {
      padding-top: 25px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="class1" style="background-color:#9BCB3B;">
    <p>left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="class2" style="background-color:#1AB99E;">
    <p>Top right</p>
  </div>
  <div class="class3" style="background-color:#F36F25;">
    <p>Buttom right</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was actually very helpful and simple to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) or [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to have such a layout, its better than having float based layout, but keep in mind to check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid#Browser_compatibility)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "left top"
    "left bottom";
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.class1{
  grid-area: left;
}
.class2{
  grid-area: top;
}
.class3 {
  grid-area: bottom;
}

p {
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="class1" style="background-color:#9BCB3B;">
    <p>left</p>
  </div>
  <div class="class2" style="background-color:#1AB99E;">
    <p>Top right</p>
  </div>
  <div class="class3" style="background-color:#F36F25;">
    <p>Buttom right</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```